# VBA to get custom data in excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to do exactly what is shown in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MswEPIFTEVU

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is a bit too broad, you need to come up with some code and then ask a specific question

Comment: Good basic [web-scraping tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrPEAljQjRM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM)

Comment: I am trying to do as its shown in this youtube vi. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MswEPIFTEVU however the file I downloaded from this video is also not working. :(

when I run code, nothing happens. and there is no error message.

Comment: Need something like this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MswEPIFTEVU

have a look at this, https://imgur.com/a/Uhqxy9M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [XMLHTTP request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) instead to get your data which is a lot faster. This assumes your links are in column A sheet 1 starting from cell A1.
It grabs the telephone numbers and returns them to column B next to the links.
If you have large number of links this method is far more effective than the method you are considering.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, links(), http As Object, results(), URL As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'URL are in column A sheet 1, starting at A1

        If lastRow = 1 Then
            ReDim links(1, 1): links(1, 1) = .Range("A1")
        Else
            links = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
        End If

        ReDim results(0 To UBound(links, 1) - 1)
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(i, 1), "http") > 0 Then
                URL = links(i, 1)
                Set html = GetHTMLDoc(http, URL)
                results(i - 1) = GetNumber(html)
                Set html = Nothing
            End If
        Next
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(results, 1) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results)
    End With

End Sub
Public Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal http As Object, ByVal URL As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    html.body.innerHTML = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    Set GetHTMLDoc = html
End Function
Public Function GetNumber(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As String
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(html.querySelector(".container").innerText, Chr$(10))
    GetNumber = Replace$(arr(8), "Number : +", vbNullString)
End Function
```

---

You can re-write as follows to get city, name, carrier

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, links(), http As Object, results(), URL As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'URL are in column A sheet 1, starting at A1

        If lastRow = 1 Then
            ReDim links(1, 1): links(1, 1) = .Range("A1")
        Else
            links = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
        End If

        ReDim results(0 To UBound(links, 1) - 1)
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(i, 1), "http") > 0 Then
                URL = links(i, 1)
                Set html = GetHTMLDoc(http, URL)
                results(i - 1) = GetNumber(html)
                Set html = Nothing
            End If
        Next

        For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
            .Cells(i + 1, 2).Resize(1, UBound(results(i)) + 1) = results(i)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
Public Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal http As Object, ByVal URL As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    html.body.innerHTML = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    Set GetHTMLDoc = html
End Function
Public Function GetNumber(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, outputArr(0 To 2)
    arr = Split(html.querySelector(".container").innerText, Chr$(10))
    outputArr(0) = Replace$(arr(2), "Name : ", vbNullString)
    outputArr(1) = Replace$(arr(10), "Carrier : ", vbNullString)
    outputArr(2) = Replace$(arr(14), "City : ", vbNullString)
    GetNumber = outputArr
End Function
```

If for some reason positional matching isn't working you can use the following version of the function `GetNumber`:

```
Public Function GetNumber(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, outputArr(0 To 2), i As Long
    arr = Split(html.querySelector(".container").innerText, Chr$(10))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(arr(i), "Name") > 0
            outputArr(0) = Replace$(arr(2), "Name : ", vbNullString)
        Case InStr(arr(i), "Carrier") > 0
            outputArr(1) = Replace$(arr(10), "Carrier : ", vbNullString)
        Case InStr(arr(i), "City") > 0
            outputArr(2) = Replace$(arr(14), "City : ", vbNullString)
        End Select
    Next i
    GetNumber = outputArr
End Function
```

Comment: It seems wonder and thanks from bottom of my heart for reply, but it seems like the website is not returning results, because of high trafic. non the less its not working right now, should work when website -starts working. But for now its only giving me number, I want 'name', carier' and 'city' in colum B,C and D. I suppose thats how it will work ?

Comment: One moment. So you don't want the number at all?

Comment: I have numbers, thats how I created the url in colum A. need to know the name and 'city' most importantly.

Comment: Hello Qharr, In some of the urls, which have image or display pic of the contact, it is giving me gender, area, email, instead of name, carier and city. like in this one. http://smsprank.ga/true/pro.php?no=7414814525 

any Idea why? I notice this happens in url with DP only, and website only allow fetching 120 data per day which is okay, but can you modify it so It gives name, carier and city of DP contacts instead of gender, area, email. keeping in mind url have both DP and non DP contacts.

Comment: outputArr(0) = Replace$(arr(0), "Name : ", vbNullString)
    outputArr(1) = Replace$(arr(8), "Carrier : ", vbNullString)
    outputArr(2) = Replace$(arr(12), "City : ", vbNullString)

works for me, seems like I have to categorize the whole result first for bad data(data of contacts with DP) then rescan with new code.

Comment: @DeepakJindal I will have a look later today and update the code.

Comment: What are DP and non DP? This url  http://smsprank.ga/true/pro.php?no=7414814525 items are in the correct order. Are you sure it is one that fails?

Comment: I have given you a different version of one of the functions to use.

Comment: Hi QHarr, have a look at the result file, https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rubf2fpp0plfuq/Screenshot%20%2836%29.png?dl=0